# Is there a simple match for objects containing array where the array content order doesn't matter?

Tags: karate

I was trying to compare objects that contain arrays when I don't care about the order of keys or the order of array contents. Contains deep is close to what I need except that I need to use it both ways around to ensure there are no missing elements in the data. Ideally I want a version of `==` that is order-insensitive. Is there is a better option to what I have below?

```
    * def sample = { user: ['read', 'write', 'append'], public: ['read', 'append'] }
    * def test = { public: ['append', 'read'], user: ['write', 'read', 'append'] }
    * match sample contains deep test
    * match test contains deep sample
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 2 `contains only`. Yes we haven't designed a deep contains, it is rarely needed.

```
* def sample = { user: ['read', 'write', 'append'], public: ['read', 'append'] }
* match sample.public contains only ['append', 'read']
* match sample.user contains only ['write', 'read', 'append']
```

For completeness, although this may be overkill unless you want to re-use schema pieces, you can do this:

```
* def user = ['write', 'read', 'append']
* def public = ['append', 'read']

* def sample = { user: ['read', 'write', 'append'], public: ['read', 'append'] }
* match sample == { user: '#(^^user)', public: '#(^^public)' }
```

EDIT: note that newer versions of Karate support a `match contains only deep`: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#match-contains-only-deep

Comment: Thanks - they are both helpful ideas. I guess I am pushing the boundaries of Karate as I am focussing on testing unknown systems not known ones so all my matching needs to be more flexible. I trying to establish patterns that will keep the tests readable and as close to Karate syntax as possible.