# How to check all objects from arraylist is present in json using data driven in karate

Tags: karate

Two json files as below. Want to check one by one all the arraylist is "data" is present in "response" json. ie fist list `{a : aa, b : 2}` from data is present in "response " then seocnd list`{a : bb, b : 5}` from data and so on .
Both the json's are dynamic. So length and contains (key-value) of jsons changes everytime.

```
def response = [{a : aa, b : 2, c : 4}, {a : bb, b : 5, d : 1, e : 1}, {a : cc, b : 5}……]

data = [{a : aa, b : 2}, {a : bb, b : 5}]
```

Trying lots but no success please help me........!

1. Below throws an error `Expected an operand but found <`  on `* match` statement

```
Scenario Outline: Verify all list from arraylist is present in json
* def response = [{a : aa, b : 2, c : 4, d : 1, e : 1}, {a : bb, b : 5, d : 1, e : 1}, {a : cc,   b : 5, d : 1, e : 1}……]
* match response contains '#(^<data>)'

    Examples:
      | data|
```

2. ```
    * match response contains deep data
   ```

throws an error  `<eval>:1:5 Expected ; but found data`

Comment: the next time you ask a question please a) use well-formed JSON that others can cut and paste and b) simplify your example, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @PeterThomas, Thanks Sir, updated the JSON .  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65938339/is-there-a-simple-match-for-objects-containing-array-where-the-array-content-ord  
Solutions is good when json has constaint attributes, BUT in mycase, these josn are dynamic in nature.

Comment: @PeterThomas, Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one line in Karate: https://github.com/intuit/karate#match-contains-deep

```
* match response contains deep data
```

Comment: for deep command , i am getting error  `javascript evaluation failed: deep expected, <eval>:1:5 Expected ; but found data` . got same error when tried same example from https://github.com/intuit/karate#match-contains-deep  .  Note : i am using `karate 0.9.4` version. Is there an issue with version

Comment: @user3302083 use the latest version please. `deep` is new

Comment: Thanks @peter it is working with new version 1.0.0